# Maven version plugin reports not generating

Tags: maven, version-control, dependencies

I want to take a report of what are the newer versions available on the dependencies using `mvn site`
command.
Version goal used is `dependency-updates-report`. Report do generate in command.`versions:dependency-updates-report`
But not in `mvn site` command.

This is my **pom.xml** file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.dexter</groupId>
    <artifactId>vulnTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
                <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <format>HTML</format>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>dependency-updates-report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-configuration/commons-configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>20030311.152757</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <!--  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <reports>
              <report>project-team</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>-->
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have do define the plugin and goal as reporting:

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <id>dependency-updates-report</id>
                    <reports>
                        <report>dependency-updates-report</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Now `maven-site-plugin` will use `versions-maven-plugin` and you should see in log:

`[INFO] Generating "Dependency Updates Report" report    --- versions-maven-plugin:2.7`

Comment: Thanks. It worked that way too. I also manged to do it by mentioning the report plugging only.